# Arch Linux Boot Halts on “Started Authorization Manager.”

Tags: linux, boot, unix

I was using Arch Linux on my laptop, and during the shutdown procedures there was something making it wait and during that time my laptop ran out of batteries.

Now when I try to boot it halts. This is the last screen that is displayed before continuing to the page that halts:

```
    starting version 222
    /dev/sda4: clean, ###/### files, ###/### blocks
    [    3.######] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
    [    3.######] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
    [    6.######] [drm:intel_not_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [1915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
    [    6.######] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [1915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
```

***After*** this screen, it halts on a blank screen with '_' solid for a second, then it starts flashing forever. With quiet turned off on the boot commands, this page contains the following:

```
    Starting WPA supplicant...
               Starting Authorization Manager...
                                [   OK   ] Started WPA supplicant.
                                                 [   OK   ] Started Authorization Manager.
                                                                                          _
```